What is the RAM clearance of the Noctua NH-U12DX i4 CPU air cooler?
UPDATE: I just realized this cooler height (158 mm) exceeds what I believe to be the max allowable for my chassis (157 mm). Thanks for everyone's help
I'm curious about what the above is. I'm trying to upgrade the air cooling in my Dell Precision 5820 and need at least 34.5 mm of RAM clearance. To be clear, the dimension I'm looking for is the one highlighted in red below:


It’s less than 45nm, so say 40 nm, to be safe. You’ll want slim modules. You’ll have to measure the modules and the board. We can’t help unfortunately, I would be more worried, about getting the sides back on with a cooler like that.  You need a slim cooler for that Dell model more than likely

@jdrch - Then I don’t understand your question, if you only need 35 nm and you have ~40 nm of clearance then you should be fine with the clearance on the memory. However, the model in that screenshot doesn’t seem to match, the one your asking. Have you asked Noctua for the measurements? When I need them for my current build they provided them with hesitation

@Ramhound AFAICT, the 40 mm dimension is a guess by you and not an actual measurement or specification. I'm looking for one or the latter 2. If not from someone who knows the specification, then from someone who owns or has access to the same cooler.

@jdrch - Fine; What memory modules do you have, what are the height of them.  I’ll measure my actual cooler.

AMD or Intel. That will make a difference.

@Ramhound AAAACK I just realized the cooler is too tall for my chassis, a point I already covered in a spreadsheet on this end tracking various solutions. Thanks for your assistance. I updated my OP accordingly.

Although this cooler wound up being too tall for my chassis, turns out you can find the max allowable RAM height by finding the largest height here. The largest number I could find for DDR4 Crucial RAM - which I use - in an Intel socket is 41 mm.

I found many modules on that page that exceed 41nm
